# NSTextView - NSParagraphStyle lost after new line

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I'm changing the NSAttributedString - property of NSTextView with

```
- (void)textStorageDidProcessEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSMutableParagraphStyle * myParagraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    myParagraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10;

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,self.string.length);

    [[self textStorage] addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                               value:myParagraphStyle
                               range:range];
}
```

After `- (void)insertNewline:(id)sender` the caret has a bigger size when I jump back to this line. The caret includes the line-spacing, not just the font-height.

[image]

After jumping back

[image]

It feels like I'm in a different context after entering a newline. The font size itself is the same during typing, but the caret is larger and also the selection-area of course.

Comment: I don't really see the difference between the first graphic and the second graphic (it still looks like the width between the two lines is the same).

Comment: It seems like a small bug of the NSTextView... The only thing I can think about is that when you're setting the paragraph style, you are actually setting it only from 0 to the current string length, that changes when you start to write again.

Comment: I think you have to check the string length first how much it is considering. I think it is not taking after word that caret symbol

Comment: i have tried your code but is not showing me an issue. Can you please paste your more code. So that will sort it out